# Create a property page without admin rights to install a target

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm developing a visual studio plugin (VS 2010 to 2017). I need project specific configuration.

Visual Studio already has GUI for project specific properties like compiler and linker options which can be opened by right-clicking the project and choosing properties.

How can I create auch a propery page without requiring admin rights to install a target?
A possible solution would be to deliver a target file inside the VSIX and to point VS to this file. Bu I don't know whether and how this is possible.

The new property page shall be shown on existing C/C++ projects. So creating my own project type is not an option.

I already found
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/881782/Creating-custom-UI-property-pages-sheets-in-Visual
and
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsproject/2009/06/18/platform-extensibility-part-2/
but it looks like I have to create (and store) a target to get VS to show the property page.

**Update**
A proposed solution are property sheets.
How can I inject targets or items (PropertyPageSchema) without modifying the vcxproj and without installing something globally (C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild). That means I want to define new settings without the user needing to install something additional to the vsix.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a property page for your project type so that users can view and change properties in projects that are based on your template. And you also could set some default property values in your custom property page, which doesn't require admin rights.

Detailed steps about how to create property page for your project type, please refer to this document.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc826178(v=vs.140).aspx#Anchor_8

**Update:**
If you want to add your custom properties for C++ project, I suggest you add custom property sheet because as the document you mentioned that "*The Visual C++ project system does not support project subtypes.*".

Following document introduce detailed steps about how to create custom property sheet for C++ project.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319827/Sharing-project-properties-in-Visual-Cplusplus

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to use my own property page for already existing C++ projects. The documentation ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/project-subtypes ) says that C++ projects don't support subtypes. So I don't understand how I can add the property page to an existing C++ project.

Comment: I have update my answer which provide the information about how to use custom property sheet in C++ project. Because subtypes is not supported in C++ project.

Comment: How can I inject targets/items without changing the vcxproj or installing something globally? (see edit)